# Currency filter in angular breaks for values > 1000, only if rounded

Tags: angularjs

These work as expected:

```
{{ 999 | currency }}
{{ 999 | number:0 | currency }}
{{ 1000 | currency }}
{{ 50000 | currency }}
```

These do not print anything:

```
{{ 1000 | number:0 | currency }}
{{ 50000 | number:0 | currency }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? [The `number` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) returns a string, and [the `currency` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) expects a number, so obviously that can't work. I guess you simply want to use the third parameters of the `currency` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom currency filter. Check this:

```
app.filter('currencyFilter',
  ['$filter', '$locale', function(filter, locale) {
     var currencyFilter = filter('currency');
     var formats = locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
     return function(amount, num, currencySymbol) {
       if (num===0) num = -1;
       var value = currencyFilter(amount, currencySymbol);
       var sep = value.indexOf(formats.DECIMAL_SEP)+1;
       var symbol = '';
       if (sep<value.indexOf(formats.CURRENCY_SYM)) symbol = ' '+formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
       return value.substring(0, sep+num)+symbol;
     };
}]);
```

And use it like the following:

```
{{1000 | currencyFilter:0}} // $1,000
{{1000.234 | currencyFilter:0}} // $1,000
{{1000.55555 | currencyFilter:2}} // $1,000.56
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hg6y7ZUgarlF8B7RkTOP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `currency` filter expect it's input to be number, but in case of `1000 | number:0` it gets string, that it can't parse as number.

If you use `number` filter to round the number, then you may create your own filter:

```
myApp.filter('round', function(val) {
  return Math.round(val);
});
```

And use it as: `{{ 1000 | round | currency }}`